# How to pass the reference of unique_ptr.get() to a function

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, unique-ptr

I have the following code, however it reports `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char*&' from an rvalue of type 'std::unique_ptr<char []>::pointer {aka char*}'`. I am wondering if I can buffer allocation in a function for a unique_ptr in this way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

void buffer_test(char* &buffer){

    buffer = new char[100];
}

int main()
{



    std::unique_ptr<char []> buffer{};

    buffer_test(buffer.get());

    std::cout << buffer[0] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "finish";
}
```

Comment: What is the point of making an alias pointer?

Answer (score 4):

`unique_ptr::get` does not return a reference to the pointer object within the `unique_ptr` object. It returns the pointer value. You get a copy of it, not a reference.

So you cannot pass that value to a function with takes a non-const reference to a pointer. If you want to fill in the `unique_ptr`'s actual stored pointer value, you will *have to * pass the `unique_ptr` itself to `buffer_test`, or just have `buffer_test` return the pointer it allocates.

Or even better, have it return a `unique_ptr` to the buffer it allocates. Because there's basically no reason not to.